How to solve the Fatal Python error: Aborted in anaconda while running a model training with fit?
I'm new in deep learning. I'm a student and I would like to perform a transfer learning in my research.
When I'm running the training with fit of my model, it shows the error below.
I'm using anaconda 2.5.4
2024-04-21 18:33:42.681880: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2024-04-21 18:33:42.683001: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/process_util.cc:146] Creating new thread pool with default inter op setting: 2. Tune using inter_op_parallelism_threads for best performance.
OMP: Error #15: Initializing libiomp5md.dll, but found libiomp5 already initialized.
OMP: Hint This means that multiple copies of the OpenMP runtime have been linked into the program. That is dangerous, since it can degrade performance or cause incorrect results. The best thing to do is to ensure that only a single OpenMP runtime is linked into the process, e.g. by avoiding static linking of the OpenMP runtime in any library. As an unsafe, unsupported, undocumented workaround you can set the environment variable KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK=TRUE to allow the program to continue to execute, but that may cause crashes or silently produce incorrect results. For more information, please see http://www.intel.com/software/products/support/.
Fatal Python error: Aborted
Main thread:
Current thread 0x00001920 (most recent call first):
File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\preprocessing\image.py", line 2591 in apply_affine_transform
File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\preprocessing\image.py", line 2013 in apply_transform
File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\preprocessing\image.py", line 384 in _get_batches_of_transformed_samples
File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\preprocessing\image.py", line 116 in getitem
File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 1022 in _peek_and_restore
File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 869 in init
File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 1010 in init
File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 1262 in init
File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 1582 in get_data_handler
File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1501 in fit
File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 65 in error_handler
File "e:\doctorat\source azo 06-04-2024\litesrgan_mobilenetv3small_ssdlite_impl\litesrganmbnet.py", line 61 in 
File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\py3compat.py", line 356 in compat_exec
File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 473 in exec_code
File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 615 in _exec_file
File "C:\Anaconda\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 528 in runfile
File "C:\Users\UNIVERSITE TOAMASINA\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_4132\677467036.py", line 1 in 
Redémarrage du noyau...
I don't really understand the error and would like to have some explaination and solutions, please.
Thank you!
I tried to re install tensorflow but it doesn't work


As an unsafe, unsupported, undocumented workaround you can set the environment variable KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK=TRUE to allow the program to continue to execute, but that may cause crashes or silently produce incorrect results.

This is the most common solution, but Intel warns this could cause issues. You can set the variable like this:
import os
os.environ["KMP_DUPLICATE_LIB_OK"] = "TRUE"  

And another solution that works for me is that trying to rename/delete the libiomp5md.dll. The file is in your anaconda3/envs/your_env_name/Library/bin folder or just anaconda3/Library/bin if not in an env.
